# Что такое коллекция объектов в php

Tags: php, объекты

Собственно есть задача, создать объект со вложенной коллекций объектов tickets. Но что это такое?

Вот есть объект со вложенным объектом tickets:

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [email] => asd@asd.ru
    [phone] => +79243000155
    [tickets] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ticketType] => Adult
            [person] => Array
                (
                    [fullName] => Хабраков Иван Иванович
                    [FirstName] => Иван
                )
        )
)
```

`tickets` нужно представить в виде **коллекции объектов**. А как он должен выглядеть и, соответственно, создаваться?

Answer (score 1):

Скорей всего в задаче подразумевается использовать это: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Коллекция_(программирование)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

Можете реализовать свою коллекцию по интерфейсу: http://php.net/manual/ru/class.ds-collection.php

> **Collection**
>   Данный интерфейс предназначен для описания базовых функций работы с множеством объектов. Он наследует интерфейсы Countable и Iterable, что позволяет получать количество объектов в коллекции и выполнять обход и применение пользовательской функции для каждого объекта коллекции. Интерфейс коллекции подразумевает, что в коллекции находятся объекты одного типа.

В вашем случае больше всего подойдёт реализация коллекции **наборы**.

> **Реализации наборов**
>   Наборы представлены единственной реализацией UniqueStore.
>   Объекты в хранилище UniqueStore. Уникальность объектов обеспечивается за счет метода getIdentity(), который возвращает идентификаторы объектов. В хранилище UniqueStore не могут присутствовать несколько объектов с одинаковыми идентификаторами.
>   Внутренняя структура хранилища уникальных объектов UniqueStore построена на основе ассоциативных связей между объектами и их идентификаторами. Это дает возможность реализовывать все операции хранилища с помощью ассоциативных выборок, что очень сильно повышает скорость его работы. Сложность работы алгоритмов хранилища уникальных объектов равна O(1), что означает, что время установки/получения объектов не изменяется в зависимости от размера хранилища. 
>   Хранилище уникальных объектов UniqueStore поддерживает любые типы данных для значений.

Примеры использования набора:

```
namespace Rmk\Collection;

use \UnexpectedValueException as UnexpectedValueException;
use \InvalidArgumentException as InvalidArgumentException;
use \stdClass as stdClass;

include '../../bootstrap.php';

$set = new UniqueStore('stdClass');

$obj1 = new stdClass();
$obj2 = new stdClass();
$obj3 = new stdClass();

// Добавление объектов в хранилище.
$set->add($obj1);
$set->add($obj2);
$set->add($obj3);

// Повторно объекты в хранилище добавлены не будут.
$set->add($obj3);

try {
    $set->add(new UnexpectedValueException);
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $exc) {
    echo 'Значение не подходит по типу.';
}

// Обход хранилища.
$set->each(function($value, $thisSet) {
            /**
             * @TODO: Обработка хранилища.
             */
        }
);

// Удаление объектов из хранилища.
$set->remove($obj1);
$set->remove($obj2);
$set->remove($obj3);

// Преобразование в массив.
$array = $set->toArray();
```

**Источник:** https://habrahabr.ru/post/144182/

Comment: А вот ds collection это подключаемое расширение. И оно требует php седьмой версии? А как быть с 5х?

Comment: @ZhiV есть допустим такая реализация: https://habrahabr.ru/post/64840/ но, здесь реализация коллекции "Список". Впрочем, разница с "набором" лишь в том, что используя "список", если вы допустите ошибку в логике скрипта, то у вас есть возможность создать дубликаты билетов в "списке".

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я буду не прав, и где то поторопился, но почему не сделать коллекцию например так ?

Я не отрицаю, что сейчас здесь мало методов, еще можно добавить поиск по билетам и еще возможно что-то, но задача задать вектор мышления.

```
<?php

Class Ticket {
    protected $ticketType;
    protected $person;

    public function __construct($ticketType,$person) {
        $this->ticketType = $ticketType;
        $this->person     = $person;
    }

}

Class Collection implements Iterator, Countable {

    private $tickets = array();
    private $position;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    //Добавить элемент в массив
    public function push($ticket) {
        if($ticket instanceof Ticket === false) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Попытка добавить не верный тип');
        }
        array_push($this->tickets,$ticket);
    }

    //Взять последний добавленный
    public function pop() {
        array_prop($this->tickets,$ticket);
    }

    //Ниже Методы для реализации интерфейса Iterator
    function rewind() {
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    function current() {
        return $this->tickets[$this->position];
    }

    function key() {
        return $this->position;
    }

    function next() {
        ++$this->position;
    }

    function valid() {
        return isset($this->tickets[$this->position]);
    }


    function count(){
        return count($this->tickets);
    }
}

$ticketJhon = new Ticket('emptyTicket',"John");
$ticketJane = new Ticket('emptyTicket',"Jane");

$collection = new Collection();

$collection->push($ticketJhon);
$collection->push($ticketJane);

foreach($collection as $ticket) {
    print_r($ticket);
}

$ticketStr = 'Не билет';
$collection->push($ticketStr);
```